# Best way to avoid plot.factor and the boxplot

Tags: r, plot

I have the below data set

```
d <- data.frame(value = rep(c(120,110,100,90,80),2), 
                group = c(rep("test1",5),rep("test2",5)),
                g.num = c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5)))

d$group <- factor(d$group)
```

When I run the following code, `plot(d$group, d$value, type="p")`, I get:[image]

But I don't want a boxplot I want something like this:
[image]

The code I used to generate the above figure

```
 plot(d$g.num, d$value, type="p", axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "")
 axis(1, 1:2, levels(d$group))
 axis(2)
```

The root of my problem is that when you pass a factor to the plot function, the plot.factor method is used, which generates a boxplot.  With that in mind, what is a good work around?  One last thing, I did run the plot command on`d$group` when this variable was a character, instead of a factor.  This however, generated the same result.

Finally, I would ideally like the answer to use base graphics.  However, if this can be done easily with other graphics packages, it might be useful.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `plot.default(d$group, d$value, type="p")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving my comment to an answer.  You can avoid the boxplot by using `plot.default()` directly.

```
plot.default(d$group, d$value, type="p")
```